# Compare a dictionary key to all other keys in the same dictionary

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, iteration

I have a dictionary with author names as keys and values of `None`. I want to use fuzzywuzzy to compare these author names to see if there are similar ones that I can combine.

So far I am using two dictionaries (they have the same data in both of them) and then using a double `for` loop. I want to optimize it further, and I was thinking of using Dictionary Composition, but I couldn't figure out how to get that working with my fuzzy compare logic.

My code is below where the two dictionaries are identical.

Example dictionary is:

```
{'Trevor Jacobs': None, 'Josh Francis': None, 'Marcie Lank': None, 'Marcie H. Lank': None}
```

```
import uuid
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

authorToDelete = {}
dictOfAllData1 = {'Trevor Jacobs': None, 'Josh Francis': None, 'Marcie Lank': None, 'Marcie H. Lank': None}
dictOfAllData2 = {'Trevor Jacobs': None, 'Josh Francis': None, 'Marcie Lank': None, 'Marcie H. Lank': None}

for key in dictOfAllData1:
    for key2 in dictOfAllData2:
        str1 = ' '.join(key.split()) #some spaces are different so I handle those here
        str2 = ' '.join(key2.split())
        ratio = fuzz.ratio(str1, str2)
        if fuzz.ratio(str1, str2) > 85 and dictOfAllData1[key] == None:
            dictOfAllData1[key] = uuid.uuid1()
        elif ratio > 85:
            if str1 != str2:
                authorToDelete[key2] = None
            else:
                dictOfAllData1[key] = uuid.uuid1()

for deleteMe in authorToDelete:
    dictOfAllData1.pop(deleteMe)
```

This is the code I have so far. It works, but it takes longer than I think it should (about 4 seconds with a dictionary of ~700 keys)

My question is how can I make this more efficient? Is there a way I can use `if in dict` or something like that instead of my second `for` loop?

Edit:
I took the advice in the comments below and posted it in Code Review too. I will update if I find an answer

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. There are definitely ways you can optimize the code, but without all the data it's impossible to write a conclusive answer. FWIW you could use `itertools.combinations(dictOfAllData1, 2)` to get rid of the second `for` loop. As well, you could consider asking on [codereview.se] since you're asking how to improve working code.

Comment: @wjandrea I updated the post to have an example dictionary

Comment: @TrevorAllen I don't understand the logic `if str1 != str2: authorToDelete[key2] = None`. At this point, how do you know that `key2` is in `dictOfAllData1` and the subsequent `pop` will be successful?

Comment: @a_guest this I will only hit that `if` if the ratio is high but the first key already exists. If that is the case, then I will add that key to my dictionary to delete. `dictOfAllData1` is the same as `dictOfAllData2` meaning that if one key exists in one, then it exists in the other. I delete the `key2` because I am choosing to accept the first name I come across.

Comment: Shouldn't you have only one match > 88? That being: `Marcie Lank  -> Marcie H. Lank -> ratio: 88`?

Comment: @GrajdeanuAlex. For this specific data set, yes that would work. In my full script I have other names (I changed these names from my actual data) that will need a slightly lower threshold.